# Circular references with shared_ptr and weak_ptr and trees

Tags: c++

I hope I am not double posting... I am trying to solve a "tree/graph" construction problem, where each node can have any number of parents and children, and can also have its own parent as one of its child. So the construction problem is pretty straightforward, no problem there. The problem is memory deallocation. Let me explain. Here is how my node class is defined:

```
class Node{
public:
    // A bunch of utility functions and an empty virtual destructor (only a 
    // printf there)
private:
    std::list<shared_ptr<Node>> m_children;
    std::list<weak_ptr<Node>> m_parents; // To avoid circular references
}
```

The problem specifically happens when I have a node that's a parent to one of its own parents. To be more precise I suspect this happens whenever a node is a parent to any node in its path from the starting node... The objects are not released due to circular reference...

I tried to solve the problem by adding this member:

```
std::list<weak_ptr<Node>> m_weakChildren;
```

in which I put weak references to the child I want to add if it is already in the parents path. Now, quite logically when you think about it, I get a segmentation fault due to fact that the parent object is destroyed.

Does anyone has any idea on how to solve my problem ? That would be greatly appreciated !

Subsidiary question: The class that is managing the tree also has a class that indexes the Nodes for fast look up, using shared_ptr. Sadly, this class is destroyed before the tree itself. The question is: how can we know which class members are to be destroyed first?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Basically you need a graph, don't bother with your own implementation when there's boost.graph http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html

Comment: How are you notifying your `m_weakChildren` about destruction of the parent? This should be part of class `Node`'s destructor implementation, shouldn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So you add an observer to the pointers?  Memory management in a graph isn't (or shouldn't be) the responsibility of the nodes, but of the graph itself.

Comment: @JamesKanze Good point! Yes there should be a `Graph` class introduced, managing this finally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` is *not* an appropriate solution for nodes in
a graph (even if the graph is acyclic).  Graphs should be
managed by a higher level structure (`class Graph`?), and this
structure should manage the memory.  (Or... you can use the
Boehm garbage collector.  Graphs are one thing where garbage
collectors are exceptionally good at managing—there's
a reason why all of the benchmarks from pro-garbage collection
people use extensive graphs.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thing is, and it is my mistake for pointing it out, I have absolutely no way of knowing in advance the number of states, I merely know an upper bound. Maybe, I can build a dynamic container container that will manage the memory, and use adjacency matrix to represent the graph. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: @DerickThePoney There's no problem with using a `Node` class.  The only thing is that it should be managed by a `Graph` class, much in the way the nodes of an `std::list` are managed by `std::list`.  (On the other hand, depending on the dynamics of the graph, using some sort of dedicated node allocator could be be a real win.)

Comment: Thanks, it took me some time, but I finally got it right. And no memory leaks. Thing is, I think that using an adjacency matrix is going to simplify my life... So I went for this solution. When I'll be processing my graph, I migth have to add some nodes. Node addition with my algorithm is constant in time, the only problem is adding one line and one column to the adjacency matrix...